# double data on mysql

Tags: php, logical-and

I use the php operator && to select multiple data so that there is no duplication on mysql.
Does the code that I use below run fine? Is there a more simple use of PHP operators?

```
$date= date('Y/m/d');
$cekcount = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `pending_media` where `mediaid`='$dielz'"));
$cekcount2 = mysql_num_rows(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `media` where `mediaid`='$dielz'"));
$selectcount = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `media` where `date`='$date' AND `uplink`='$nam'");
$cekcount3 = mysql_num_rows($selectcount);
if($cekcount == 0 && $cekcount2 == 0 &&  $cekcount3 == 0){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO pending_media VALUES('','$nam','$dielz')");
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with that method of checking if 3 variables are all zero.

Comment: In my opinion, this snippet is not "fine to run".  You need to upgrade to `mysqli_` functions.  And you could use at least one JOIN to reduce the total trips to the database.  If `$dielz` and `$nam` are coming from user submissions or otherwise untrusted sources, you should be using prepared statements for security reasons.

Comment: And use mysql's count() function to count records as opposed to counting them on the php side.

Comment: Furthermore, you should be using immediate conditional checks so that you aren't making unnecessary database calls after the first call is a disqualifier.  You can spare the database some strain with `LIMIT 1` as well.  ...ugh, I guess I need to write all this in an answer.

Comment: Where is `$dielz` coming from?

Comment: @Shadow why do you feel this isn't a mysql issue? seeing you removed the tag for it.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner because the question is on the use of php logical operators and perhaps a recommendation on which api to use.

Comment: @Shadow So mack's answer shouldn't be in there then. Seeing the OP's using  a different api. His answer has no bearing on the logical operator. Same thing goes for Jamsheed's; both did not address the question, IMHO anyway. Voting as unclear.

Comment: @Shadow I don't just deliver what OPs ask for.  I provide what I feel is the best approach using best practices to the best of my knowledge, because I never answer with the intent to serve just one person -- I know that thousands of potential researchers will read my answers.  This is why I have upgraded the api, shown security enhancements, offered debugging checkpoints, and generally put forth a considered answer.  I have been generous here. Do you really feel the downvote is necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrade to mysqli, I'll recommend object-oriented syntax because it is nicer to work with.

In accordance with the best practice of "minimize calls to the database", I'll condense your three queries into a single, united SELECT call then check for a non-0 result.

My untested suggestion using mysqli's object-oriented syntax (I did test the SELECT query in PHPMyAdmin):

```
$query = "SELECT SUM(tally)
          FROM (
              SELECT COUNT(*) AS tally
              FROM pending_media
              WHERE mediaid = ?
              UNION ALL
              SELECT COUNT(*)
              FROM media
              WHERE mediaid = ? OR (date = ? AND uplink = ?)
          ) t";
$conn = new mysqli("localhost", "root","","dbname");
$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $dielz, $dielz, $date, $nam);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($tally);
$stmt->fetch();
if (!$tally) {
    $stmt->close();
    // insert qualifying data
    $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO pending_media VALUES ('',?,?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $nam, $dielz);
    if ($stmt->execute()) {
        echo "Insert Query Error"; // $stmt->error;
    }else{
        echo "Success";
    }
}
```